# How to interpolate in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2017 windows form application and SQL Server. For example, here is a Table with data,

```
ColumnA | ColumnB
1099    | 57
1209    | 58
1213    | 59
1227    | 60
1228    | 61
```

If we pass the exact value (that is) **1213** in ColumnA, I can able to get **59** from columnB data. 
Now, how to interpolate if we pass **1210** in ColumnA:

```
(1210-1209)/(1213-1210) = (x-58)/(59-x) ==> x = 58.25
```

Kindly help to code this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL? Remove question tags that do not apply and add the version-specific tag for the DBMS.

Comment: Do you want to do that in TSQL or C#?

Answer (score 2):

Try below query:

```
declare @tbl table (ColA int, ColB int);
insert into @tbl values
(1099 , 57),
(1209 , 58),
(1213 , 59),
(1227 , 60),
(1228 , 61);

declare @toInterpolate int = 1210;

select min(colB) + (@toInterpolate - min(ColA))*1.0/(max(colA) - min(colA))
from (
    select top 2 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN ColA > @Value THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY ABS(ColA - @Value)) rn,
                 ColA,
                 ColB
    from @tbl
    order by rn
) a
```

NOTE: I assumed, that values in `ColumnB` are increasing.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Note that the difference is in `abs`, not only value itself :)

Comment: It only works for the 1210, but not for 1220 for examble

Comment: @DanielBrughera It works also for 1220, outputs 59.5 as it should

Comment: Sorry, with 1221 to 1226 and 1214 to 1218

Comment: In some cases the pair of values that you get are both lower or greater than the input

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
CREATE TABLE #YourTable (ColumnA float, ColumnB float)
INSERT #YourTable values
(1099 , 57),
(1209 , 58),
(1213 , 59),
(1227 , 60),
(1228 , 61);

DECLARE @Value float = 1221

select *, a.ColumnB + (@Value - a.ColumnA)/ISNULL(NULLIF((b.ColumnA - a.ColumnA),0),1)
from (
    select top 1 ColumnA,
                 ColumnB
    from #YourTable
    where ColumnA <= @Value
    order by ColumnA desc
) a
cross join (
    select top 1 ColumnA,
                 ColumnB
    from #YourTable
    where ColumnA >= @Value
) b

DROP TABLE #YourTable
```